# Dynamic Metatags in Laravel using views

Tags: laravel, metadata, laravel-views

I have a setup where I am trying to load dynamic metadata (og) for a range of different pages in Laravel. The basic structure of my application view is:

```
meta.blade.php 
base.blade.php (extends meta) 
layout.blade.php (extends base) 
index.blade.php (extends layout) // multiple instances of this
```

My problem lies that I can't (or don't know how to) load dynamic meta from the `meta.blade.php` to `index.blade.php`

Example of meta php file:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Example" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Example">
<meta property="og:url" content="Example" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Example">
<meta property="og:type" content="Example" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="Example" />
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about using [`@include`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#including-subviews)?

Comment: Not sure how that will resolve my problem given the layout structure?